# Equivalent of a database table in SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, development, list, page-layout, content-type

I'm making a Publishing site, and part of this site will display information about company products.  We have a number of products, and each one should have its own description page.  The description of each will be fairly standardised, with each Product having a standard set of properties, e.g. Name, Description, Image.

If I was doing this in a standard web app, I might have a Product table in a DB and automatically generate the pages from each of the rows in that table.

I'm not sure how to go about this in SharePoint however.  Would I have a product Content Type, and then maybe a Product list, and perhaps a Product Page Layout from which the page for each product is completed?  Or something totally different?  I'm a bit clueless as to how to go about this, so thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spot on, but don't expect any of the more advanced database capabilities such as referential integrity and joins.

Have a look at this discussion as well: [using SharePoint as a database](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/sharepoint-for-transactional-systems/3364#3364).

Comment: As a note to this, I've just come across the page "Using SharePoint Lists vs. Database Tables" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413971.aspx) which provides good guidance on when to use a database as opposed to a list, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I will sugest your second option to define a product content type with the fields you need and then a Product Page Layout based on this contant type.
In my opinion this is the best approch for publishing site.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that Business Data Catalog (BDC) also can be used to integrate your productdata in the pages using business data meta data field.