# I can't retrieve usefull information from sharepoint database 

Tags: custom-database

Please explain why  sharepoint database always have to be independent ? 
Please let me know if its possible to save all created data in sharepoint lists on the special database which we have designed ?

I can't retrieve usefull information from sharepoint database . I think sharepoint databases with special design is not suitable for external reporting. 
How can I find a way which anabling me to obtain sharepoint database as well as tables that retrieve from sql database ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a very bad idea to interact with the SharePoint database directly, and in fact, MS will not support this.  If you need to interact with the content then you need to go through the APIs, Web Services, or some other supported connector.  For example, there is a connector available for SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) that can be used to bring your content into a data warehouse or other reporting environment.

It is not possible to save SharePoint content to a "custom" database.  You can expose custom databases via SharePoint, but it isn't SharePoint content.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these related discussions:

- [SharePoint for Transactional Systems](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/sharepoint-for-transactional-systems/3364)
- [Equivalent of a database table in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/3406)